# Finding the multiplicity of a fifth-degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials

If you have a fifth-degree polynomial equation and you know a root of this polynomial is equal to $1$, then why can you find the multiplicity of the root $1$ by dividing by $z-1$ or by differentiating the polynomial? See the image below for an example.

[What is the multiplicity of the root 1?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okNVQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial $p(x)$ has a root $\alpha$ of multiplicity $k$ if and only if $(z-\alpha)^k$ is a factor of $p(x)$, and $(z-\alpha)^{k+1}$ is not.

Therefore, if we start with $p(x)$, and divide by $(z-\alpha)$ a total $k$ times, until we cannot divide any more, this shows that $p(x)$ has a factor $(z-\alpha)^k$, but not $(z-\alpha)^{k+1}$. Hence, $\alpha$ is a root of multiplicity $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(z)$ is the fifth degree polynomial and 1 is a root, then $p(z)$ can be re-written as $p(z)=(z-1)f(z)$ where $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree four. So, dividing $p(z)$ by $z-1$ will simply give the polynomial $f(z)$. Now 1, is a root of the equation $p(z)=0$ or $(z-1)f(z)=0$. We can check if 1 is a root of $f(z)$ and if it happens to be, then by the same arguement as before, $f(z)$ can be re-written as $f(z)=(z-1)g(z)$ for some polynomial $g(z)$ with degree 3. Combining the above we get $p(z)=(z-1)^2g(z)$ which tells us that the multiplicity of the root 1 is at least 2. And we continue the same way for $g(z)$ etc.